# How can I use fread to read in a file value by value?

Tags: c++, file, fread, bin

I used `fwrite` to store some data and now I'm trying to use `fread` to read the data from the txt file for processing. I want to read the values individually but I can't figure out how you'd do that. This is what I have tried:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main () 
{
  FILE * pFile;
  long lSize;
  unsigned short * buffer;
  size_t result;

  pFile = fopen ( "myfile.txt" , "rb" );

  // obtain file size:
  fseek (pFile , 0 , SEEK_END);
  lSize = ftell (pFile);
  rewind (pFile);

  // allocate memory to contain the whole file:
  buffer = (unsigned short *) malloc (sizeof(unsigned short)*lSize);

  // copy the file into the buffer:
  result = fread (buffer,1,lSize,pFile);

  printf("%uz\n", result);

  // terminate
  fclose (pFile);
  free (buffer);
  return 0;
}
```

The above program compiles fine but when I run it with `./a.out` I get a Segmentation fault. When I run it with `sudo ./a.out` I don't get seg fault but nothing prints out. 
Any idea what I can do to fix it?

Comment: Do some error checking here: `pFile = fopen ( "myfile.txt" , "rb" );`

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ What would I check? That just opens the file. As long as I got the filename correct it should work fine.

Comment: You never checked the return value against `NULL`!

Comment: printing result as string - that is probably reason of your segfault

Comment: @PiotrNycz I updated that and now it just prints `524z`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problems I see:

**Allocating more memory than needed**

After

```
lSize = ftell (pFile);
```

`lSize` is set to the number of characters in the file, not the number of `unsigned short`s. Hence, you need

```
buffer = malloc(lSize);
```

See [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc). If you are using a C++ compiler (as your `C++` tag seems to imply), you need to cast the return value of `malloc`.

**Wrong format specifier**

```
printf("%s\n", result);
```

uses the wrong format specifier to print `result`. You need to use

```
printf("%zu\n", result);
```

That line is the most likely culprit for the segmentation fault you are seeing.

---

**Reading objects one by one**

You can certainly use:

```
size_t count = lSize/sizeof(short);
for ( size_t i = 0; i < count; ++i )
{
   unsigned short number;
   result = fread (&number, sizeof(unsigned short), 1, pFile);        
}
```

You can also use:

```
size_t count = lSize/sizeof(short);
for ( size_t i = 0; i < count; ++i )
{
   result = fread (buffer+i, sizeof(unsigned short), 1, pFile);        
}
```

Comment: But the values that are written to the file are of type unsigned short. When I do what you said I just get a bunch of `1z` printed out to the screen.

Comment: The return value of `fread` is the number of objects read. If you read one object at a time, the value of `result` will be `1`. You are seeing `1z` as output due to an error in the format I had suggested. It needed to be `"%zu"` instead of `"%uz"`. I fixed the error in the answer.